# Вычисляет ли компилятор значение методов константной строки QString

Tags: c++, qt, оптимизация, компилятор, qstring

Есть следующий фрагмент кода:

```
QRegularExpression Reg("^\\[ABC=\\d+.?\\d*\\]\\n$");
if(line.contains(Reg))
{
    curABC = line.mid(5,line.length()-7);
}
```

В последней строке стороннему человеку может быть неясно, откуда взяты числа "5" и "7".
5 -- это длина фрагмента "[ABC=",
7 -- длина "[ABC=]\n".
По-хорошему, последнюю строку стоит привести к виду:
`curABC = line.mid(QString("[ABC=").length(), line.length() - QString("[ABC=]\n).length())`
Но не охота каждый раз вычислять значение, которое и так известно, да и заводить переменные тоже кажется не лучшим решением, с другой стороны, возможно компилятор сам поймет, что метод всегда будет возвращать 5 и 7 и тогда можно просто использовать написанный выше вариант.

Comment: `стороннему человеку может быть неясно, откуда взяты числа "5" и "7".` это называется `магические числа`. Минимальные усилия с вашей стороны -- это написать комментарий, который поясняет что это и откуда

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, не надо делать всё через одно место, благо в регулярных выражениях есть [*группировки*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#%D0%93%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B8), которые можно вычленять отдельно (см. [документацию `QRegularExpression`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html#normal-matching))<sup>*</sup>:

```
QRegularExpression rx("^\\[ABC=(\\d+.?\\d*)\\]\\s*$");
QRegularExpressionMatch match = rx.match (line);

if (match.hasMatch ()) {
    curABC = match.captured (1);
}
```

---

По вопросу — всё зависит от деталей реализации `QString` и того насколько умным окажется компилятор. На практике ответом почти наверняка будет «**нет**».

Дабы явно заставить компилятор вычислить какое-то значение во время компиляции, в С++11 ввели [`constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr). А для работы с `constexpr`-строками в С++17 появился [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view). Так что сейчас можно сделать что-то такое:

```
#include <string_view>

constexpr size_t prefix_len = ("ABC="sv).length();
```

И конечно не стоит забывать старый добрый ламповый Сишный метод:

```
size_t prefix_len = sizeof("ABC=") - 1;
```

---

<sup>* `\n` заменено на `\s*` ради смягчения синтаксиса, к примеру это не имеет отношения, но обычно это желаемое поведение</sup>